# postgres: how to calibrate idle_in_transaction_session_timeout

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I want to set the idle_in_transaction_session_timeout parameter group setting of our RDS postgres database. Any suggestions on how I should approach this? Whats the right value? What should I look at to decide on the optimal value.

Comment: Did you configure it in the Parameter Group in the management console? Or, this references a CLI command you can use: [idle_in_transaction_session_timeout - AWS Prescriptive Guidance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/prescriptive-guidance/latest/tuning-postgresql-parameters/idle-in-transaction-session-timeout.html)

Comment: thanks @JohnRotenstein, I just updated the question. I know how to set it, want to understand how to figure out whats the right value for the setting.

Answer (score 0):

`idle_in_transaction_session_timeout` defines the maximum time an idle transaction can stay open before being automatically rolled back.

To choose an optimal value for the parameter you can follow below steps:

- Identify typical transaction durations for your applications and start with a conservative value slightly above your longest expected transaction duration.
- Monitor database performance and resource usage after applying the change.
- Look for metrics like:

  - Active connections, idle connections, blocked connections.
  - Average transaction duration, long-running transactions.
  - Lock waiting time, CPU and memory utilization.

Now based on the metrics and observations Adjust and monitor:

- If there are many idle transactions being rolled back, it might indicate a value too low. Increase it gradually.
- If resource usage remains high due to long-running idle transactions, the value might be too high. Decrease it cautiously, ensuring long-running processes can complete.
- Continuously monitor and adapt the setting based on your observed behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Ask the people who coded the application how long a database transaction can take in the worst case. Then set `idle_in_transaction_session_timeout` to ten times that value. I would suggest 10 seconds as a reasonable minimum value for this parameter, but typically it will be much higher.